# Python Kivy cannot use Video Player ffpyplayer ignored

Tags: python, kivy, video-player

I am building my first app with kivy but cannot make the VideoPlayer work.

There is a error-message stating:
**Provider: ffpyplayer(['video_ffmpeg'] ignored)** which seems to be the problem.

I have already installed ffpyplayer (aswell as Pillow) using pip install.

When I type:

```
import kivy
print(kivy.kivy_options['VIDEO'])
```

It says: **('gstplayer', 'ffmpeg', 'ffpyplayer', 'null')**

However, here is a minimal example:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.videoplayer import VideoPlayer


class VideoPlayerWindow(Widget):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(VideoPlayerWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.player = VideoPlayer(
            source=r"D:\kivy-thelab\resources\commercial_free\videos\pilates1.mp4",
            state='play',
        )

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return VideoPlayerWindow()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

And the full debugging output:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\Home\.kivy\logs\kivy_23-05-08_10.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.3.3
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.3.1
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.4.5
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.1.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\Home\miniconda3\envs\kivy_env\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.9.0 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Nov 26 2020, 07:53:15) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\Home\miniconda3\envs\kivy_env\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge log fired. Processing...
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge finished!
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 189 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [ImageLoaderFFPy] Using ffpyplayer 4.5.0
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_ffpyplayer 
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [VideoFFPy   ] Using ffpyplayer 4.5.0
[INFO   ] [Video       ] Provider: ffpyplayer(['video_ffmpeg'] ignored)
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.6.0 - Build 27.20.100.8682'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Intel'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Intel(R) HD Graphics 620'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 6
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.60 - Build 27.20.100.8682'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[ERROR  ] [Image       ] Error loading <D:\kivy-thelab\resources\commercial_free\videos\pilates1.mp4>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code is creating a `VideoPlayer`, but is not using it. Try modifying your `VideoPlayerWindow` like this:

```
class VideoPlayerWindow(FloatLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(VideoPlayerWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.player = VideoPlayer(
            source=r"D:\kivy-thelab\resources\commercial_free\videos\pilates1.mp4",
            state='play',
        )
        # add the VideoPlayer
        self.add_widget(self.player)
```

Test if the above works.

Comment: Thank you, it works now. But there are still multiple Error messages coming from the debugging logger: **[ERROR  ] [Image       ] Error loading <resources/commercial_free/videos/pilates1.mp4>** can i just ignore this?

Comment: Yes. The `VideoPlayer` tries to load the `.mp4` file as an `Image`, but it cannot and throws an exception.